# xpath query to process XML output

Tags: xml, xpath

I am trying to process some XML output on a Juniper router through slax. The following is the XML data that I am working on.

```
<filesystem>
<filesystem-name>/dev/ad2s1f</filesystem-name>
<total-blocks junos:format="34G">70754788</total-blocks>
<used-blocks junos:format="5.6G">11800836</used-blocks>
<available-blocks junos:format="25G">53293572</available-blocks>
<used-percent> 18</used-percent>
<mounted-on>/var</mounted-on>
</filesystem>
```

I want to get `available-blocks` attribute value of `"25G"`. `@attribute` is not working for me or my syntax is wrong. Can anyone help with a xpath query? I'm looking for something like this:

```
var $test = $var_data/available-blocks[@*];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your xmlns defined? Then it should be as easy as:

```
<configuration xmlns:junos="junos">
<filesystem>
<filesystem-name>/dev/ad2s1f</filesystem-name>
<total-blocks junos:format="34G">70754788</total-blocks>
<used-blocks junos:format="5.6G">11800836</used-blocks>
<available-blocks junos:format="25G">53293572</available-blocks>
<used-percent> 18</used-percent>
<mounted-on>/var</mounted-on>
</filesystem>
</configuration>
```

Xpath 2.0:

```
//available-blocks/@*
```

[**Online Demo**](http://www.videlibri.de/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?compatibility=Enable%20all%20extensions&data=%3Cconfiguration%20xmlns%3Ajunos%3D%22junos%22%3E%0D%0A%3Cfilesystem%3E%0D%0A%3Cfilesystem-name%3E%2Fdev%2Fad2s1f%3C%2Ffilesystem-name%3E%0D%0A%3Ctotal-blocks%20junos%3Aformat%3D%2234G%22%3E70754788%3C%2Ftotal-blocks%3E%0D%0A%3Cused-blocks%20junos%3Aformat%3D%225.6G%22%3E11800836%3C%2Fused-blocks%3E%0D%0A%3Cavailable-blocks%20junos%3Aformat%3D%2225G%22%3E53293572%3C%2Favailable-blocks%3E%0D%0A%3Cused-percent%3E%2018%3C%2Fused-percent%3E%0D%0A%3Cmounted-on%3E%2Fvar%3C%2Fmounted-on%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Ffilesystem%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fconfiguration%3E&extract=%2F%2Favailable-blocks%2F%40*&extract-kind=xpath3&printed-node-format=text&output-format=adhoc&input-format=xml&dot-notation=unambiguous)

Comment: @student_XML786 You are welcomed. Feel free to upvote once reach the required 15 repo. Up'd.